# Correct approach to validate attributes of an instance of class

Tags: python

Having a simple Python class like this:

```
class Spam(object):
    __init__(self, description, value):
        self.description = description
        self.value = value
```

I would like to check the following constraints:

- "description cannot be empty"
- "value must be greater than zero"

Should I:
1. validate data before creating spam object ?
2. check data on `__init__` method ?
3. create an `is_valid` method  on Spam class and call it with spam.isValid() ?
4. create an `is_valid` static method on Spam class and call it with Spam.isValid(description, value) ?
5. check data on setters declaration ?
6. etc.

Could you recommend a well designed/Pythonic/not verbose (on class with many attributes)/elegant approach?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use Python [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) to cleanly apply rules to each field separately, and enforce them even when client code tries to change the field:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, description, value):
        self.description = description
        self.value = value

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description

    @description.setter
    def description(self, d):
        if not d: raise Exception("description cannot be empty")
        self._description = d

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        if not (v > 0): raise Exception("value must be greater than zero")
        self._value = v
```

An exception will be thrown on any attempt to violate the rules, even in the `__init__` function, in which case object construction will fail.

**UPDATE:** Sometime between 2010 and now, I learned about `operator.attrgetter`:

```
import operator

class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, description, value):
        self.description = description
        self.value = value

    description = property(operator.attrgetter('_description'))

    @description.setter
    def description(self, d):
        if not d: raise Exception("description cannot be empty")
        self._description = d

    value = property(operator.attrgetter('_value'))

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        if not (v > 0): raise Exception("value must be greater than zero")
        self._value = v
```

Comment: +1 elegant solution thanks, dont' you think is a little bit verbose for a small class like that?

Comment: Agreed, it isn't the prettiest solution. Python prefers free-range classes (think chickens), and the idea of properties controlling access was a bit of an afterthought. Having said that, this wouldn't be much more concise in any other language I can think of.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I realize this is an old question, but based on the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) (albeit for Python 3), should `self.description = description` use an underscore, i.e. `self._description = description`, or does that not matter? Is this necessary or merely something similar to Python's version of "private" variables?

Comment: @JohnBensin: Yes and no. `self.description = …` assigns through property, whereas `self._description = …` assigns directly to the underlying field. Which one to use during construction is a design choice, but it's usually safer to always assign through the property. For example, the above code will raise an exception if you call `Spam('', 1)`, as it should.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Thanks for pointing that out. I was completely unaware of the difference in assignment. Based on a quick test, this difference also holds true for accessing a member variable, which I didn't know either. Very neat.

Comment: I do not think it is too verbose. The alternative is for it to be possible to set the value to invalid values.

Comment: Is this supposed to work in Python 2? Because I'm trying the first variant, and the setter just doesn't get run.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson yes it should work in Python 2. Have you added logging to confirm that the code never runs?

Answer (score 12):

If you only want to validate the values when the object is created AND passing in invalid values is considered a programming error then I would use assertions:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, description:str, value:int):
        assert description != ""
        assert value > 0
        self.description = description
        self.value = value
```

This is about as concise as you are going to get, and clearly documents that these are preconditions for creating the object.

Comment: thanks Dave, using assert, how do i specify to the client of that class what went wrong (description or value)? Don't you think that assertion should be used just to test conditions that should never happen?

Comment: You can add a message to the assert statement e.g `assert value > 0, "value attribute to Spam must be greater than zero"`.
Assertions are really messages to the developer and should not be caught by client code, since they indicate a programming error.  If you want the client to catch and handle the error then explicitly raise an exception such as ValueError, as shown in the other answers.

Comment: To answer your second question, yes asserts should be used to test conditions that should never happen - that is why I said "if passing in invalid values is considered a programming error...".  If that is not the case then don't use asserts.

Comment: `def  `should be inserted prior to `__init__`

Comment: Thanks @datapug, fixed the typo.

Comment: Instead of using assert you should consider raising errors since it's possible for the user to disable assert statements with [`python -O`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement)

Answer (score 7):

Unless you're hellbent on rolling your own, you can simply use [formencode](http://formencode.org/). It really shines with many attributes and schemas (just subclass schemas) and has a lot of useful validators builtin. As you can see this is the "validate data before creating spam object" approach.

```
from formencode import Schema, validators

class SpamSchema(Schema):
    description = validators.String(not_empty=True)
    value = validators.Int(min=0)

class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, description, value):
        self.description = description
        self.value = value

## how you actually validate depends on your application
def validate_input( cls, schema, **input):
    data = schema.to_python(input) # validate `input` dict with the schema
    return cls(**data) # it validated here, else there was an exception

# returns a Spam object
validate_input( Spam, SpamSchema, description='this works', value=5) 

# raises an exception with all the invalid fields
validate_input( Spam, SpamSchema, description='', value=-1)
```

You could do the checks during `__init__` too (and make them completely transparent with descriptors|decorators|metaclass), but I'm not a big fan of that. I like a clean barrier between user input and internal objects.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to only validate those values passed to the constructor, you could do:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, description, value):
        if not description or value <=0:
            raise ValueError
        self.description = description
        self.value = value
```

This will of course will not prevent anyone from doing something like this:

```
>>> s = Spam('s', 5)
>>> s.value = 0
>>> s.value
0
```

So, correct approach depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: this is my actual approach; but i don't like it when attributes number raise and\or constraints checks are more sophisticated.It seems to clutter the init method too much.

Comment: @system: you can separate validity check into its own method: there are not hard and fast rules about this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`pyfields`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/):

```
from pyfields import field

class Spam(object):
    description = field(validators={"description can not be empty": lambda s: len(s) > 0})
    value = field(validators={"value must be greater than zero": lambda x: x > 0})

s = Spam()
s.description = "hello"
s.description = ""  # <-- raises error, see below
```

It yields

```
ValidationError[ValueError]: Error validating [<...>.Spam.description=''].
  InvalidValue: description can not be empty. 
  Function [<lambda>] returned [False] for value ''.
```

It is compliant with python 2 and 3.5 (as opposed to `pydantic`), and validation happens everytime the value is changed (not only the first time, as opposed to `attrs`). It can create the constructor for you, but does not do it by default as shown above.

Note that you may wish to optionally use [`mini-lambda`](https://smarie.github.io/python-mini-lambda/) instead of plain old lambda functions if you wish the error messages to be even more straightforward (they will display the failing expression).

See [`pyfields` documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/) for details (I'm the author by the way ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on yet another validation library - **convtools models** ([docs](https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html) / [github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools)).

**The vision of this library is:**

- validation first
- no implicit type casting
- no implicit data losses during type casting - *e.g. casting 10.0 to int is fine, 10.1 is not*
- if there’s a model instance, it is valid.

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import Union

from convtools.contrib.models import ObjectModel, build, validate, validators

# input data to test
SpamTest = namedtuple("SpamTest", ["description", "value"])


class Spam(ObjectModel):
    description: str = validate(validators.Length(min_length=1))
    value: Union[int, float] = validate(validators.Gt(0))


spam, errors = build(Spam, SpamTest("", 0))
"""
>>> In [34]: errors
>>> Out[34]:
>>> {'description': {'__ERRORS': {'min_length': 'length is 0, but should be >= 1'}},
>>>  'value': {'__ERRORS': {'gt': 'should be > 0'}}
"""


spam, errors = build(Spam, SpamTest("foo", 1))
"""
>>> In [42]: spam
>>> Out[42]: Spam(description='foo', value=1)
>>> In [43]: spam.to_dict()
>>> Out[43]: {'description': 'foo', 'value': 1}
>>> In [44]: spam.description
>>> Out[44]: 'foo'
"""
```