# Make a class instance attribute read-only in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, properties, attributes

I am trying to wrap some of my modules into classes and have started playing with properties.

Working on combining these two answers together: [making instance attribute read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6304123/3346915) and [validating attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825580/3346915).

I want to be able to create an instance of DataFolder class:

```
df = DataFolder(owner="me", path="/.data")
```

After that I want to be able to allow editing the `owner` attribute, but not the `path` attribute. I want to be able to validate the attributes at the moment of initialization (both `path` and `owner`) and afterwards (yet `owner` only).

```
class DataFolder(object):
    _path = None

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,owner,path):
        self.path = path
        self.owner = owner

    @property
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def owner(self):
        return self._owner

    @owner.setter
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def owner(self,owner_value):
        if "me" not in owner_value:
            raise Exception("invalid owner")
        self._owner = owner_value

    @property
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    @path.setter
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def path(self,path_value):
        if self._path is not None:
            raise AttributeError("Cannot edit path of existing data folder")
        if "dat" not in path_value:
            raise Exception("invalid folder")
        self._path = path_value
```

**Is it correct/best to use the global variable `_path = None` and check `if self._path is not None:` in `@path.setter`?** The code works fine, but I am wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable way to do it - it's a *class attribute*, not a *global variable*. I would raise a `ValueError` rather than base `Exception` for an invalid argument, though. As this appears to be working code, you might be better at [codereview.se].

Comment: Thank you! Will use the ValueError instead. It's getting confusing with the "_" in front of private variables, but I hope to get used to them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine to me, except one thing: `_path = None` belongs to a class.

This is just a small improvment:

```
class DataFolder(object):
    def __init__(self, owner, path):
        self._path = None  # now it is an instance variable.
        self.path = path
        self.owner = owner

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self._owner

    def _validate_owner(self, owner_value):
        if "me" not in owner_value:
            raise ValueError("invalid owner")

    @owner.setter
    def owner(self, owner_value):
        self._validate_owner(owner_value)
        self._owner = owner_value

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    def _validate_path(self, path_value):
        if self._path is not None:
            raise AttributeError("Cannot edit path of existing data folder")
        if "dat" not in path_value:
            raise ValueError("invalid folder")

    @path.setter
    def path(self, path_value):
        self._validate_path(path_value)
        self._path = path_value
```

Using:

```
d = DataFolder('me', 'data')
print(d.path, d.owner)
d.path = 'new_data'
```

Output:

```
('data', 'me')
new_me
AttributeError: Cannot edit path of existing data folder
```

Comment: Could you outline how you think this is better? Why not just delegate to the getter from `__init__`, rather than duplicate the code? And why are you accessing the validation on the class, not the instance (which will interfere with inheritance later on)?

Comment: But this doesn't have the behaviour of the OP's original code, i.e. that you can set one of the attributes only once...