# Validating python class attributes

Tags: python

I want to add validations for my class attributes. On exploring, I came across multiple libraries [google appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses), [dj](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#field-types) have their own property classes to validate attributes. Since its a common problem, Is there any python library which just provides basic validators ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct approach to validate attributes of an instance of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825452/correct-approach-to-validate-attributes-of-an-instance-of-class)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pyfields`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/), it makes it very easy to add validation to class fields, independently of how you create the constructor (although `pyfields` also provides ways to create the constructor easily).

For example:

```
from pyfields import field

class Position:
    x = field(validators=lambda x: x > 0)
    y = field(validators={'y should be between 0 and 100': lambda y: y > 0 and y < 100})

p = Position()
p.x = 1
p.y = 101  # error see below
```

yields

```
valid8.entry_points.ValidationError[ValueError]: 
  Error validating [Position.y=101]. InvalidValue: y should be between 0 and 100.
  Function [<lambda>] returned [False] for value 101.
```

It is fully compliant with `mini-lambda` and `valid8`'s validation lib, so that it is easy to add many validators to your fields, while keeping code readability :

```
from pyfields import init_fields
from mini_lambda import x
from valid8.validation_lib import is_in

ALLOWED_COLORS = {'white', 'blue', 'red'}

class Wall:
    height: int = field(validators={'should be a positive number': x > 0,
                                    'should be a multiple of 100': x % 100 == 0},
                        doc="Height of the wall in mm.")
    color: str = field(validators=is_in(ALLOWED_COLORS),
                       default='white',
                       doc="Color of the wall.")

    @init_fields
    def __init__(self, msg):
        print(msg)


w = Wall("hello world!", height=100)
print(vars(w))
```

See [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields) for details (I'm the author by the way ;) )

Answer (score 0):

validation in python classes can make from method class.you should see the object-oriented programming in python articles for more detail.

```
from datetime import datetime
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, years):
        self.age =  years

    @property
    def age(self):
        return datetime.now().year - self.birthyear

    @age.setter
    def age(self, years):
        if years < 0:
            raise ValueError("Age cannot be negative")
        self.birthyear = datetime.now().year - years

# p = Person(-1)
# ValueError: Age cannot be negative

# p = Person(10)
# p.age = -1
# ValueError: Age cannot be negative

p = Person(19)
print(p.age)       # 19

p.age = p.age + 1
print(p.age)       # 20

p.birthyear = 1992
print(p.age)       # 23
```

or try this link:
https://smarie.github.io/python-valid8/